# Smartphone locked with no access to Gboard Keyboard

Tags: adb

(First excuse my bad English, It's not my mother tongue)

Before my smartphone (Wiko Freddy) was locked, somebody disable GBoard on it, and reboot the phone.

I read a lot of articles and try a lot of tools on my computer (Windows 10 x64) from the net, but actually nothing unlocked this problem.

When connecting the phone with a USB cable to Windows 10 :

- the phone is in "charging mode"

On the phone, USB Debugging Mode seems active, but not detected from the tools who requested to activate this option on the phone before continuing.

List of products/tools tested :

- DroitKit
- FoneDog Toolkit for Android
- Free Android Data Recovery
- iMyFone D-BAck for Android
- iMyFone LockWiper (Android)
- Jihosoft Android Phone Recovery
- MyPhoneExplorer
- ScrCpy
- SnapPea
- UltData for Android
- UnlockGo (Android)
  And other products removed from the pc.

Some of the tested tools inform that they can unlock only Samsung phone.
Some are only trial version.

In device manager (Windows) :
=> Android Device

- Android Composite ADB Interface

=> Other devices : (3 times Android without installed drivers)

- Android
- Android
- Android

I try to update drivers but Windows says that the last drivers are still installed.
=> Wiko-Freddy USB drivers
=> Google USB Drivers

I try to use ADB commands.
But the device is unauthorized.
D:_adb-tools>adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
37dc5a88        unauthorized      <=====

I don't see any confirmation dialog box on the phone to allow remote connexion (from windows).

I'm sure that this problem can be resolved without reset the phone in the original configuration. I would like to preserve all datas on the phone.

I would like to know How to use ADB commands to :

- Force the unauthorized status to authorized
- Reactivate GBoard
- and change the charging mode to MTP mode

### By advance, many thanks for your help.
Regards,

Hi Alexcs (and eveybody)

Thank you very much for your reply.

As I'm a novice, and try to understand, can you give me more details  on this solution please.

- With this solution, is there any risk for the data's ?
- When I search the stock ROM for the Wiko Freddy on the net, there are a lot of sites who propose this file, with different size.
  Do you have any recommendation for choosing the right one ?
- How to put the phone in EDL mode ?

I just know the recovery mode when pressing Power on and volume down on the phone on boot.
Options are :
Reboot system now
Reboot to bootloader
Apply update from ADB       (**)
Apply update from SD card
Wipe data factory
reset wipe cache partition
Mount /system
View recovery logs
Power off

(**) When testing this option, this message appear on the mobile :
Supported API: 3
Now send the package you want to apply to the device with "adb sideload "

On windows :
List of devices attached
37dc5a88 sideload

As it's seem possible to send package and write in this case to the phone,
Is there any way to :

- copy the configuration file where the Gboard keyboard should be define to the pc
- modify this file (with any tool)
- and copy (replace) it back to the phone in the good place
- and reboot the mobile to retrieve the keyboard?

By advance, thank you very much for your help and answers about all solutions who will preserve all data's on the phone.
Regards,

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to transform an APK file to ZIP file with correct footer to upload it on android mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned android version, but I guess it's AVBv1 signed. Therefore it's possible to flash modified boot partition.

- download the stock ROM
- extract the `boot.img` file with [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-android-image-kitchen-unpack-repack-kernel-ramdisk-win-android-linux-mac.2073775)
- modify `default.prop`

  ```
  ro.adb.secure=0
  persist.service.adb.enable=1
  ```
- repack the file
- flash file into `boot` partition in [EDL](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) mode

once adb is working use scrcpy to do the necessary.